# TSQL Conditional Set

Tags: t-sql, set, conditional-statements, if-statement

I want to set a field in my table based on another field in the table.

This is the functionality that I want:

```
set result = Win if ((select status from tableY) like '%Won%')
set result = Loss if ((select status from tableY) like '%lost%')
```

This does not compile... How do I get the correct functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
set result = case when (select status from tableY) like '%Won%'
                  then 'Win'
                  when (select status from tableY) like '%lost%'
                  then 'Lost'
               -- If neither win or lose don't change a thing
                  else result
              end
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you're trying to update a column in tableY?

```
UPDATE tableY SET Result = CASE WHEN status LIKE '%Won%' then 'Win' 
                                ELSE 'Loss'
                           END
WHERE (status LIKE '%Won%'  AND COALESCE(Result,'') != 'Win')
   OR (status LIKE '%Lost%' AND COALESCE(Result,'') != 'Loss')
```